# SQL Combine Three tables without common Foreign Keys

Tags: sql

I was looking to combine three (or more) tables using SQL Server 2016. It is a music database and I am able to combine the first two without issue. Here are the two tables I am able to combine:

```
Artist
 ArtistID (pk)
 ArtName

Song
 SongID (pk)
 SongTitle

ArtistSong
 ArtSongID (pk)
 ArtistID (fk)
 SongID (fk)
```

Here is the code snippet I have created to join both tables

```
SELECT ArtName, SongTitle
FROM ArtistSong aso
JOIN Artist a ON aso.ArtistID = a.ArtistID
JOIN Song s ON aso.SongID = s.SongID;
```

I was hoping to add a third table, or maybe a fourth that does not share a foreign key with the other tables. I would like to add Album Title to the query. Here is the table for Album

```
Album
 AlbumID (pk)
 AlbumTitle (fk)
```

Should I add Album to the junction table or is there another method I should consider.

Below is an image to the ERD

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Your schema already had an appropriate junction table for albums and songs.  Then what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
...
JOIN Album_Song abs ON abs.SongID = s.SongID
JOIN Album ab ON ab.AlbumID = abs.AlbumID
...
```

Comment: Are you even certain that the OP is asking for a query?

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much:)